# Solve the equation with logs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I need to solve this equation $$3^{x+1} =15$$ with logarithms. If you can, could you please explain thoroughly?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE! Your question seems to be aiming at Maths in general rather than the software Mathematica. If it's in terms of Maths in general you could try http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E%28x%2B1%29+%3D15
if it's in terms of Mathematica: `Solve[3^(x + 1) == 15, x]`

Comment: So have you tried using logarithms? What results have you gotten, and what's giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3^{x+1} = 15 \iff \log_3(3^{x+1}) = \log_3(15) \iff x = \log_3(15) - 1$

To find $\log_3(15)$, use the change-of-base formula.

Comment: I actually find it easier to just use base $10$ or $e$ logarithms in the first place, because you end up doing the exact same calculations, but you have one less formula to remember. Personally I see the change-of-base formula as a piece of fun, but completely unneccessary, trivia. At least at the stage where you're first learning to solve $3^{x+1} = 15$. Of course, in this case it's a substitute for $\log a^b = b\log a$, so while what I said about one less formula to remember isn't completely true, I believe this formula is much more important, as this is more or less why logarithms are used.

Comment: Less chatter, more math.

Comment: It is simpler to divide by $3$ in both sides